# Mongoose Array field with default array containing values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) suggest overriding the default value of `[]` for an array field like this:

```
new Schema({
  toys: {
    type: [ToySchema],
    default: undefined
  }
});
```

I'd like to have an array of strings, with an enum and with a default value if none is supplied.

Thus, every document has type 'foo' if none is specified, but documents may be 'foo' *and* 'bar'.

Is that possible?

Comment: This second schema works fine, could you show how you save/retrieve your document ?

Comment: My bad. It *does* work in the way I specified. Not sure what I was doing, but I obviously wrote the question right and wrote my own code wrong! Might be useful to post this as an answer for future users who want to do this!

Answer (score 10):

Although the docs don't mention it, a default value can be given, in the way you'd expect.

You can have an enum array with a default value like this:

```
new Schema({
  toys: {
    type:[{ type: String, enum: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] }],
    default: ['foo']
  }
});
```